# GDB does not break in dynamically-loaded .so file?

Tags: linux, gdb, shared-libraries

In my Linux system I'm writing a program that dynamically loads some .so libraries when running.  It's like this: The executable program will search under a particular directory when it starts to run and then load all the .so files in that directory.  Please **note** that the executable and the .so are built independently, and the build of the executable does **NOT** link to the .so files.

My problem is: After I run the program(thus all the .so libraries have been loaded) with GDB attached, **I seem to be able to set a breakpoint on the code in the .so file**(the GDB prompts me that this breakpoint is set in a shared library), **but this breakpoint never actually breaks.**

**How should I make these breakpoints really work?**  During the debug session I have all the source code available at the right places, and the -g option is on.  I also removed the -O2 optimization when compiling.

Comment: What is the prompt that GDB gives about the breakpoint being in a SO? I didn't see such a message. Maybe is the "Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n])" message? If so, that's because GDB doesn't know about your symbols.

Comment: Would you mind showing the relevant code? In particular, the `dlopen()` call (flags) and subsequent usage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check that debugging information was properly loaded for .so file. Look at the output of command `(gdb) info sharedlibrary`. If your library appears with asterisk **(*)** symbol in loaded libraries table then debug symbols were not loaded and gdb unable to stop at breakpoints in this .so.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps your function is never called. Place a breakpoint at your shared library's entry point (a function that your main program fetches with `dlsym`). I have just verified that my `gdb` (7.1) does stop at such a breakpoint.

If you absolutely sure that your function is called (say, it produces some unique output that you can see) but the breakpoint you set on it is not fired, then it's a bug in `gdb` and it should be reported to the `gdb` maintainers.

Answer (score -1):

The last time this happened to me, I ran in gdb

```
info sharedlibrary
```

only to realize that I had multiple versions of the library, one built with debug symbols and the other without debug symbols. gdb was picking up the one without.

Comment: your answer is already is included in other answers